# Enabling HTTPS with Spring Security : This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: tomcat, ssl, nginx, spring-security

I'm trying to enable HTTPS for some of the pages on a web application. I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Security for the web application deployed on Tomcat with Nginx as a proxy for tomcat.

First of all, everything works alright without any HTTPS configuration. I generated a self-signed SSL certificate and installed it on Nginx. I haven't made any changes to Tomcat for enabling HTTPS as I just want Nginx to handle SSL termination. Here's my relevant Nginx configuration for SSL.

```
         listen 443;
         server_name 127.0.0.1;
         root /usr/local/server/web/webapps/ROOT;

         ssl on;
         ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;


         location / {
                    proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            }
```

My Spring security configuration for SSL looks like this:

```
<http pattern="/static/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/favicon*" security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginprocess" method="POST" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https" />
    <form-login username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/loginprocess" default-target-url="/hiring"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>
```

Now when I try to access the login page on my browser - `https://localhost/internal/login`, I get an error -

> This webpage has a redirect loop

The logs in Spring Security look like below:

```
12:34:55.240 [http-bio-8080-exec-33] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at       position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
12:34:55.240 [http-bio-8080-exec-33] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking    match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
12:34:55.240 [http-bio-8080-exec-33] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
12:34:55.240 [http-bio-8080-exec-33] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint - Redirecting to: https://localhost/internal/login
12:34:55.241 [http-bio-8080-exec-33] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'https://localhost/internal/login'
```

I tried playing with requires-channel for some time, but didn't really work out. Any help / pointers would be great.

### Update

I tried using the below configuration and the redirect loop error isn't there anymore. However, authentication fails with these logs -

```
03:29:28.603 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request:  FilterInvocation: URL: /loginprocess; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
03:29:28.603 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint - Redirecting to: https://localhost/internal/loginprocess
03:29:28.603 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'https://localhost/internal/loginprocess'

03:29:28.609 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /loginprocess' doesn't match 'POST /loginprocess
03:29:28.609 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/loginprocess' matched by universal pattern '/**'

03:29:28.614 [http-bio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /loginprocess at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
03:29:28.614 [http-bio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
03:29:28.615 [http-bio-8080-exec-20] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed:    org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Authentication method not supported: GET
```

I'm wondering if this is the same problem again as Spring Security sends a redirect to the browser and it comes back with a GET request. But if the login landing page is HTTPS and Spring considers it secure because of RemoteIPValve, why is above a problem again?

### Solution

<strike>I didn't add the internalProxies parameter in the RemoteIpValve, which was causing the problem.</strike> Some IP addresses are enabled in internalProxies by default (in my case, it was). The problem was that authentication was working intermittently. I enabled logs for RemoteIpValve and observed that proxy IP is in IpV6 format, which is not matching with internalProxies and hence RemoteIpValve isn't enabled for that request, hence the problem. I commented out the `#fe80::1%lo0    localhost` line on my Mac OS X and the problem has gone.

By the way, the configuration in @M. Deinum's answer seems to work well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HTTPS connection is handled by NGINX. The connection to your application is a HTTP connection. So basically secure on the outside, insecure on the inside.

Spring Security uses the `isSecure()` method from the [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure()) to determine if it is a secure, by default this checks the protocol to be https.

As you are using tomcat you can configure an additional valve, the RemoteIpValue[3](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html) to influence the behavior of the `isSecure()`, `getRemoteAddr()` methods (and some others).

```
     <Valve
       className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
       internalProxies="192\.168\.0\.10|192\.168\.0\.11"
       remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
       proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
       protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
       />
```

Add the above to the `<Host >` element (ofcourse you might need to remove/modify the internal proxies parameter).

In your Nginx configuration add the X-Forwarded-proto header.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header              Front-End-Https   on;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

Or simply remove the checks for a secure channel and assume everything is ok...

Links

1. ServletRequest.isSecure [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure())
2. RemoteIpValve [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)
3. [NGinx SSL Proxy](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be some work. Is enabling HTTPS on tomcat a simpler option to configure and is it better in terms of security as well? What I mean is, accepting secure connections in tomcat by configuring the SSL connector, will the configuration I currently have work as it is?

Comment: Either you add the `RemoteIpValve` or add SSL to your connectors in Tomcat. Both require configuration, the RemoteIpValve seems the easiest. Another solution would be to create a servlet filter which wraps the request and overrides the `isSecure` method (and checks for the X-Forwarded-For header or something to be secure).